# Python Plotly: px.imshow only accepts 2D single-channel, RGB or RGBA images. An image of shape (5, 1440, 1920) was provided

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, plotly

I want to use Plotly to plot subplots of several images. My code is raising `ValueError: px.imshow only accepts 2D single-channel, RGB or RGBA images. An image of shape (5, 1440, 1920) was provided.Alternatively, 3- or 4-D single or multichannel datasets can bevisualized using the` facet_col`or/and`animation_frame `arguments.` error message.

```
from skimage.morphology import binary_closing, binary_dilation, binary_erosion, binary_opening, selem
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from zipfile import ZipFile
import cv2
import os


file = "./../../...zip"
image_file = "./../../images"

img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)

# use a disk of radius 3
selem = selem.disk(3)

# oprning and closing
open_img = binary_opening(img, selem)
close_img = binary_closing(img, selem)

# erosion and dilation
eroded_img = binary_erosion(img, selem)
dilated_img = binary_dilation(img, selem)

fig = make_subplots(3, 2)
fig.add_trace(px.imshow([img, open_img, close_img, eroded_img, dilated_img]), colorscale='gray')
```

Traceback:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_7558/3340337734.py in <module>
>      11 
>      12 fig = make_subplots(3, 2)
> ---> 13 fig.add_trace(px.imshow([img, open_img, close_img, eroded_img, dilated_img]), colorscale='gray')
> 
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/express/_imshow.py in
> imshow(img, zmin, zmax, origin, labels, x, y, animation_frame,
> facet_col, facet_col_wrap, facet_col_spacing, facet_row_spacing,
> color_continuous_scale, color_continuous_midpoint, range_color, title,
> template, width, height, aspect, contrast_rescaling, binary_string,
> binary_backend, binary_compression_level, binary_format)
>     509             layout["xaxis"] = dict(autorange="reversed")
>     510     else:
> --> 511         raise ValueError(
>     512             "px.imshow only accepts 2D single-channel, RGB or RGBA images. "
>     513             "An image of shape %s was provided."
> 
> ValueError: px.imshow only accepts 2D single-channel, RGB or RGBA
> images. An image of shape (5, 1440, 1920) was provided.Alternatively,
> 3- or 4-D single or multichannel datasets can bevisualized using the
> `facet_col` or/and `animation_frame` arguments.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).